# Rails 3.2.8 Remote Form Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have this form, which is not bound to any model, that I want to ajaxify. I've tried to figure out how to get it to submit via ajax, but I must be doing something wrong because it is not working (it just does a regular POST).

I can confirm that the form tag renders with a 'remote' attribute, but there is not js added anywhere to the form. I also added the :confirm just to see if that would work as well. It does not.

jquery and jquery_ujs are both loaded on the page.

```
  %form{ :action => "/newsletter", :confirm => "Are you sure?", :remote => true, :method => "post", :id => "newsletterForm"}
    %p
      = label_tag(:q, "Subscribe to our newsletter:")
    %p
      = text_field_tag(:q, nil, :placeholder => "Your email address")
      = button_to("Subscribe", :remote => true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this doing something similar with a form get:

```
  = form_tag('/signup', :method => "get", :remote => true, :id=> 'signup-form') do
    %label{:id => 'signup-label', :for=> 'signup-box'}
      Enter your email address
    = text_field_tag "signup-box", params[:signup], :class => 'text', :required => true, :id => 'signup-box'
    = submit_tag "Sign Up", :id => 'signup'
```

Controller:

```
class SignupController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts "***************************************************"
    puts "email sign up"
    puts "***************************************************"
    render :nothing => true
  end
end
```